# Running Mongodb CRUD API on azure (for Ionic)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, express, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run a MongoDB (using NodeJS and Express) on the Azure Server as a server side part of my ionic app.
Once placed on Azure I'd like to access it with my Ionic App using CRUD operations.

What steps do I go through after acquiring a Azure Portal account? Do I take Mobile Services or a simple Web Api?

Is there something specific that I need to add to the NodeJS server?

Comment: This is really broad, and a bit unclear what you're asking. You have *many* ways to run an app in Azure (you mentioned mobile services and web api - that's a matter of discussion/opinion). There are a ton of resources on the Azure site, which explain what all the options are (e.g. web apps, cloud services, virtual machines). Probably a good idea to read up on them. As far as running MongoDB, that is a bit narrower in scope, as you really need more control of your environment. Again, a bit of reading will help; then post specific programming questions here.

Comment: I'm trying to run a simple RESTful API using Node and MongoDB that I can access through my ionic app and preform CRUD operations on.

Comment: @CedricBongaerts What concern for Node and MongoDB on Azure?

Comment: could you elaberate on that, I don't really know what you mean with 'what concern'

Comment: @CedricBongaerts Do you want to know how to deploy your app? Or how to get started for developing?

Comment: I want to know how and as what to deploymy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the app using Node and MongoDB as the backend for mobile client hosted on Azure App Service, such as WebApps, Mobile Apps (recommended).

Based on my understanding, I think there are some documents that may be helpful for you, please see them below.

For Web Apps, you can refer to the tutorial [Get started with Node.js web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/).

For Mobile Apps, I think your ionic app was based on cordova, there is a tutorial for getting started with cordova [Create an Apache Cordova app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started/). And Two related blogs shown a sample of Node + MongoDB on Azure for mobile, please see below.

1. [Exposing MongoDB collections on the node.js backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/exposing-mongodb-collections-on-the-node-js-backend/)
2. [Querying MongoDB collections via the Azure Mobile Service node.js backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-mongodb-collections-via-the-azure-mobile-service-node-js-backend/)

To deploy the app to Azure App Service, you can try to publish it via FTP, git, or IDE like VS, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Will keep you posted if I have any more questions